# hosting issue in netify continously having build error

Tags: reactjs

Error Log:

```
11:04:01 AM: Failed to compile.
11:04:01 AM: 
11:04:01 AM: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\LG\Desktop\React\my-app\src\components\Portfolio\assets\video1.mp4' in '/opt/build/repo/src/components/Portfolio2'
11:04:02 AM: ​
11:04:02 AM: "build.command" failed                                        
11:04:02 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:04:02 AM: ​
11:04:02 AM:   Error message
11:04:02 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
11:04:02 AM: ​
11:04:02 AM:   Error location
11:04:02 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
11:04:02 AM:   npm run build
11:04:02 AM: ​
11:04:02 AM:   Resolved config
11:04:02 AM:   build:
11:04:02 AM:     command: npm run build
11:04:02 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
11:04:02 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
11:04:02 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
11:04:03 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
11:04:03 AM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
11:04:03 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
11:04:03 AM: Finished processing build request in 31.714s
```

Cant resolve this error .It is repetedely happening with all my projects can anyone help

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are importing the video file like this.

```
import Video from "C:\Users\LG\Desktop\React\my-app\src\components\Portfolio\assets\video1.mp4"
```

Please don't include the full local URL in your file. You have to use this instead:

```
import Video from "./assets/video1.mp4"
```